# main() conditionally compiled creates conflict

Tags: c, makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

One of the file in the project directory /lib/mytest.c contains conditional main for testing purposes

```
#ifdef TEST 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
```

So to test the code I have added in the configure.ac file

```
AC_DEFINE(TEST, 1,[My description for TEST])
```

There are other files who include mytest.h. When I try autoreconf then ./configure then make i get the following error in gcc:

```
multiple definition of `main'
```

This is understandable because the files including mytest.h also have main functions in them. I want to have a standalone mytest program for testing purposes.

How do I build the project? What are the changes I need to make in Configure nad Make files?

Thanks.

Comment: `........because the files including mytest.h also have main functions in them` your header file `mytest.h` also contain `main` function? i don't understand it.

Comment: no the mytest.h is in the include folder and does not contain any main. There are other source files who include mytest.h.

Comment: Ok, So your other main function in different file (other then `mytest.c`), right? If so then have you also put condition in that to enable `main` if some condition true.

Comment: No main function in other .c files are not conditional.

Comment: So it will conflict if your macro `TEST` is defined.Try to giving reverse condition for main in your other.c file.

Answer (score 0):

In general, tracking around ifdefs to define main to allow tesrt drivers is tedious and as you have notice, error prone.

You could, as commented, just add `#ifndef TEST` in your other `.c` files with main and include the same file to possibly define`TEST`.  But then, what if you have a third, or more test drivers.

The solution I have adopted is simpler, always have one `main`, but have it call other `main` functions that are not called main, for example the regular main function could be called `main_program`m your test could be `main_test1` and a small side test could be `main_test_tiny_func`.  To keep intent clear, I generally prefix all such psudo-main functions with `main_`

I have occasionally just used comments to switch the pseudo-main I want to use, but that gets messy.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef TEST1
     return main_test1(argc, argv);
#else
#ifdef TINY_TEST 
     return main_test_tiny_func(argc, argv);
#else
     return main_program(argc, argv);
#endif
#endif
}
```

Alternately you can set a manifest constant to decide which test to run if you have many tests

```
#ifndef TEST_TO_RUN
#define TEST_TO_RUN 0
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     switch(TEST_TO_RUN)
     case 2:
          return main_test1(argc, argv);
     case 1:
          return main_test_tiny_func(argc, argv);
     case 0:
          return main_program(argc, argv);
     }
}
```

It is occasionally useful to decide at runtime which to run (regression tests for example), in that case you would use the same switch as above and eat the first arg to decide

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int test_no=atoi(argv[0]);
     argc--; argv++;
     switch(test_no)
     case 2:
          return main_test1(argc, argv);
     case 1:
          return main_test_tiny_func(argc, argv);
     case 0:
          return main_program(argc, argv);
     }
}
```